# Issues with Web Page Reactiveness

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been trying to figure out what I am doing incorrectly involving my page reactiveness. Specifically when it is shrunk to a been seen on different devices elements, overflow the container(I believe).I have included two of the html head elements as well as the media queries.

index.html

> Blockquote

```
<head>
  <html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href =yoga.css>
  <meta name="viewport"content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title> 
</head>
```

> Blockquote

Classes Page

> Blockquote

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport"content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href =yoga.css>
  <title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title>
</head>
```

> Blockquote

CSS

> Blockquote

```
@media only screen and (max-width:400px){
  form {display:flex;
      grid-template-rows:auto;
      grid-template-columns:auto;
      width:80%;
      padding-left:1em;}
    input { margin-bottom: .5em;}
    textarea {margin-bottom: .5em;}}


@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
    nav ul {display:flex;
        flex-flow:row nowrap;
        justify-content:flex-end;}
    nav li { width:7em;}
    section{ padding:0 2em 0 2em;}
    #mathero{ display:block;
            padding-bottom:1em;}
    #loungeher0{ display:block;
        padding-bottom:1em;}
    #flow{display:flex;
        flex-flow:row;}
    #mobile{display:none;}
    #desktop{display:inline;}
    }

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){
    header {font-size:120%;}
    .home {height: 50vh;
        padding:5em 0 0 8em;}
    .content {height:30vh;
        padding:1em 0 0 8em;}
    #wrapper {margin:auto;
        width:80%;}
    }
```

> Blockquote

Comment: I think the amount of code presented here doesn't quite qualify as "minimal" in regards to [mre]:). Please limit yourself to a single page that best demonstrates the issue. Also consider using Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to show the code such that we can run it ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I didn't even think about that rule. Thank you for the good tips. I will edit this post and post again

Comment: Are you intentionally having the `@media (max-width: 600px)` override the `@media (max-width: 400px)`? Screen width 399px will get both and cascade as appropriate.